# Scan a csv file for certain value with php

Tags: php, csv

I'm just wondering is it possible to have a csv file (with many values) and scan the file for a specific value with php?

Ideally if this is possible, Id also like to get the index of that value in the file (i.e what row number the value falls on).

I'm quiet new to php so I'm not sure where to start.
All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Did you look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

Not tested:

```
<?php
$search = 'mysearchstring';
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
        {
            if ($data[$c] == $search)
            {
               echo "Found in row $row in column {$c+1} <br />\n";
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! @Mark van Herpen, would it work the same if I was to search the file by row number?

Comment: Sure, just check $row for it's value, so if ($row == 5) or something

Comment: If I was to search another file for the row number that Ive just gotten, how would I even get the value of that row though? I appreciate your help !! :) @Mark van Herpen

Comment: OK, I guess that's outside the scope of this question.. You should store the value in a variable, open the second file and go through it the same way until the rownumber of this second file is the same as the first one.

Comment: Thanks a mill! you've been a great help!